# exact logistic regression with continuous predictor variables in SAS

Tags: sas

I need to use exact logistic regression with continuous predictor variables. However, the SAS example codes online provided are all for categorical predictor variables. With categorical variable, you can calculate weights ( frequency for each combination of IVs and DV). This is impossible for continuous variables.

Can anyone provide an example SAS code for exact Logistic regression with continuous predictors?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=statug&docsetTarget=statug_logistic_syntax15.htm&docsetVersion=15.1&locale=en#statug.logistic.xclexactnotes) on the EXACT statement itself has an example of a continuous variable - specify in EXACT statement.

proc logistic;
   model y= x1 x2 x3;
   exact x1 x2;
   run;

Does this not work for you for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

On the bottom of page 2 of https://www.sas.com/content/dam/SAS/support/en/sas-global-forum-proceedings/2020/4654-2020.pdf it says:

'Exact methods are not feasible when a continuously measured covariate/explanatory variable is entered into a model. While categorizing a continuous explanatory variable is possible, it may not be the most desirable option in many circumstances...'

In the same SAS paper, they proposed 'Firth Regression' ('Firth regression falls under the larger umbrellas of penalized likelihood regression techniques...') to deal with complete separation or 'rare events'. They also included several examples.

'This method is called by adding the FIRTH option into the MODEL statement of PROC LOGISTIC:'

```
PROC LOGISTIC DATA = FOO;
    MODEL Y = X1 X2 / FIRTH;
RUN;
```

Some details may escape from the paper, e.g. selection methods are not currently available with the firth option (SAS Studio). (`selection` methods: `backward`, `forward`, `stepwise`).

I hope it helps.